# Can I use different GPUs (GTX 970 and GTX 1060) together for distributed TensorFlow?

Tags: cuda, tensorflow, gpu

I currently own a 4GB Asus GTX 970 GPU. As it is now unavailable in the market, I am planning to buy 6GB Asus GTX 1060 GPU. I wish to use these GPUs together with distributed TensorFlow framework. Will TensorFlow support GTX 970 (4GB) and GTX 1060 (6GB) together? I have seen Titan and GTX being incompatible (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4013) as 'they can not talk to each other and they are of different generations'. Will above mentioned two cards work together?

Comment: what do you mean by "work together"? what you have linked to is strictly a discussion of peer to peer memory access, and the first answer is correct and the second incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you can you use both of them, although it's hard to design an efficient way of splitting the work between them because they run at different speed